# TypeScript convert object to obfuscated string

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, save, obfuscation

I am making a game in JavaScript and want to make a save system. Besides browser data I also want the user to copy the data as a string.

The problem I have is that I don't want the user to be able to modify the saved string to cheat, so I need a way to obfuscate it.

How do I do that?

Comment: Use some sort of encryption (maybe just Caesar), then obfuscate your sourcecode to hide the key.

Comment: As Jonas mentioned encrypt the output of `JSON.stringify(gameState)` for example by using any reasonable reversible encryption. Keep in mind though, someone dedicated enough WILL figure out how to decrypt the data. Therefore don't invest a disproportionate amount of time implementing this kind of "security".

Comment: A more convoluted approach would be to let the game client send the unencrypted data to a dedicated server via respective API endpoints which then in turn responds with an encrypted result. Such an approach can pretty easily end up being over-engineered, so beware.

Comment: thank you for your help